# Poisson on frequency data with many 0, underestimated output

Tags: r, probability, distributions, zero-inflation

I have got a frequency table of how many events occur within a 5-minute time window.

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
plotdata <- structure(list(events = 0:6, 
                           N = c(511468L, 75194L, 7813L, 1102L, 174L, 86L, 23L)), 
                      row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

#   events frequency
#1:      0    511468
#2:      1     75194
#3:      2      7813
#4:      3      1102
#5:      4       174
#6:      5        86
#7:      6        23
```

Explained: 7813 times there was a 5-minute timewindow in which two events occured.

I am trying to fit this data onto a poisson-curve, but I'm geting lost here. My last statistics course was waaay back in college and I'm getting lost in the terminology.

What I've tried so far:

find lambda:

```r
lambda <- sum( plotdata$events * plotdata$N ) / sum( plotdata$N )
#lambda = 0.1600879401
```

Get estimated values of poisson-distribution
Resulting in (too?) low estimated values for events > 2

```r
plotdata[, poisson.P := exp( -1 * lambda ) * lambda^events / factorial( events )]
plotdata[, poisson.N := poisson.P * sum( N ) ][]

ggplot( plotdata, aes( x = events ) ) + 
  geom_line( aes( y = N ) ) + 
  geom_line( aes( y = poisson.N), colour = "red" ) + 
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

black = counted values, red = result from poisson

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is my data not suited for a description by poisson-distribution, or..., or... ?

Underestimation on a larger number of `events` is a no-go in my usecase. So I would really like the estimated output to perform better on events > 3

Comment: Your data are indeed not like a Poisson distribution; they're considerably more like a geometric. For example, a Poissonness plot shows a distinct "kink". You can see in your plot that the black line is somewhat nearer a straight line than it is like the red curve.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you need to estimate?  In particular, what would be the limitation of using the frequencies you have observed in this large dataset?

Comment: @whuber I would like to be able to estimate the probability of events >6 (since they did not occur dring measuring period).

Comment: That's going to be problematic, because you are basically having to guess what that probability might be: you have no data (apart from the fact that you haven't recorded any such values in a dataset of almost 600K observations).  Anything you do will necessarily be an extrapolation beyond the data you have and therefore will depend strongly on your assumptions about how the probabilities change.

Comment: @whuber, ahah.. i see... I was hopig to fit a (poisson) distribution on the observed data, and then calculate odds for unobserved data. Also, if I can find the correct distribution, I can (probably) use it into a MonteCarlo analysis later on in my project.

Comment: The problem is that this clearly is not a Poisson distribution.  Unless you have additional information to suggest how the right tail ought to behave, there's almost nothing to go on.  You could set some bounds on the chances of higher numbers based on not having observed them.  Those bounds will depend on whether your observations are independent or, if not, the degree of dependency among them.  You might have lost a lot of information by simply summarizing the counts rather than tracking the data by time.

Comment: @whuber All the raw material is still available to me, but it would go a bit far to put my complete project-questions here and ask for a method :). I guess I'll have to pick up my old statistics-books, and take some youtube/coursera-lessons ;-). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This data do not seem to be following a Poisson distribution, and to me it is not clear that zero inflation is the issue. The negative binomial does give a better fit. One way to see this is (following your R code in the post):

```
 (lambda <- sum( plotdata$events * plotdata$N ) / sum( plotdata$N ) )
[1] 0.1600879
> (var    <- Hmisc::wtd.var(plotdata$events, plotdata$N) )  
[1] 0.1793297
```

A visualization for Poissonness:

```
vcd::distplot(cbind(plotdata$N, plotdata$events), "poisson")
```

[image: Poissonness plot]

And ditto for the negative binomial:

```
vcd::distplot(cbind(plotdata$N, plotdata$events), "nbinomial")
```

[image: negbinness plot]

but the fit is better, not perfect.

Comment: Thanks! this gives me a nice new starting point to work with! Time to hit the books/tutorials again on the binominal distribution :)